# Carousel image slideshow script

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I have learned to make a carousel image slideshow script with JavaScript. I think it's better to learn it from the basic than just from the framework (instant script), but I'm a newbie. I wrote this script using my technique, but I think it's terrible.

```js
var runCarousel, runTimer;
        firstval = 0;
        secondval = 0;

        function Carousel(){
        firstval += 10;
        document.getElementById('abc-container').style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
        document.getElementById('asas').innerHTML = "-" + firstval;
            if(firstval == 400)
            {
                StopRun();
                StartTimer()
                return;
            }
            if(firstval == 800)
            {
                StopRun();
                StartTimer()
                return;
            }
        runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 10);
        }

        function StartTimer(){
        secondval += 1;
        document.getElementById('asass').innerHTML = "-" + secondval;
        if(secondval == 10)
        {
            StopTimer();
            Carousel();
            return;
        }
        if(secondval == 20)
        {
            StopTimer();
            Carousel();
            return;
        }
        runTimer = setTimeout(StartTimer, 1000);
        }

        function StopRun(){
        window.clearTimeout(runCarousel);
        }

        function StopTimer(){
        window.clearTimeout(runTimer);
        }

        function firstStart(){
            setTimeout("Carousel()", 10000);
        }

        firstStart();
```

```css
#wrapper {
width:400px;
height:140px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin: -70px 0 0 -200px;
background: #383838;
overflow: hidden;
}

#abc-container {
position: absolute;
width:1200px;
height:140px;
}

#a {
width:400px;
height:140px;
background: #FF0000;
float: left;
}

#b {
width:400px;
height:140px;
background: #FFFF00;
float: left;
}

#c {
width:400px;
height:130px;
background: #00FFFF;
float: left;    
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="abc-container">
        <div id="a"></div>
        <div id="b"></div>
        <div id="c"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="asas"></div>
<div id="asass"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Great start for far but you need to work on your overall design.

Here are some tips.

### 1) Separate the css, html and javascript into their own files.

If you were place all your css into a file called "style.css" and javascript in a file called "main.js", then you could import the files from your html like so.

```
... more code
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
... more code
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

### 2) For your css, try using a creating a class for the box to share common properties.

Old Code:

```
#a {
    width:400px;
    height:140px;
    background: #FF0000;
    float: left;
}

#b {
    width:400px;
    height:140px;
    background: #FFFF00;
    float: left;
}

#c {
    width:400px;
    height:130px;
    background: #00FFFF;
    float: left;    
}
```

New Code:

```
#a {
    background: #FF0000;
}
#b {
    background: #FFFF00;
}
#c {
    background: #00FFFF;
}
.box{
    width:400px;
    height:140px;
    float: left; 
}
```

Remember to add the classes.

```
<div id="abc-container">
    <div id="a" class="box"></div>
    <div id="b" class="box"></div>
    <div id="c" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

### 3) Don't repeat yourself.

The if conditions for firstval and secondval can be combined by using or, `||`.

Old Code:

```
if(firstval == 400){
    StopRun();
    StartTimer()
    return;
}
if(firstval == 800){
    StopRun();
    StartTimer()
    return;
}
runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 10);
```

New Code:

```
if(firstval == 400 || firstval == 800){
    StopRun();
    StartTimer()
}else{
    runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 10);
}
```

### 4) Declare all variables are the top of a function.

Old Code:

```
var runCarousel, runTimer;
firstval = 0;
secondval = 0;
```

New Code:

```
var runCarousel, runTimer, firstval = 0, secondval = 0;
```

### 5) Pass the function name instead of string to `setTimeout()`

Also it's better to use multiplication when setting the timeout delay.

Old Code:

```
setTimeout("Carousel()", 10000);
```

New Code:

```
setTimeout( Carousel, 10 * 1000);
```

### 6) Attach all the global variables to a object literal.

### 7) Name variables and functions based on their operations.

- Rename `Carousel()` to `moveToNextSlide()`

### 8) Cache elements for faster lookup.

Code:

```
var infoEl = document.getElementById('asas'), 
container = document.getElementById('abc-container');
```

### 9) There needs to be a limit for `firstval` inside `Carousel()`

Add this:

```
var abc_container = 1200;
firstval += 10;
if( abc_container < firstval ){
    firstval = 0;
}
```

### 10) Use variables in place of numeric constants.

It's hard to understand the meaning of `400`. 
It seems that `400` is the width of each box.

### 11) secondval isn't needed. Just place everything inside `setTimeout()` for 10 seconds.

Better yet `seconds` as a parameter.

Old Code:

```
function StartTimer() {
    secondval += 1;
    el.innerHTML = "-" + secondval;
    if (secondval == 10 || secondval == 20 ) {
        runTimer = window.setTimeout(StartTimer, 1000);
    }else{
    ...
}
```

New Code:

```
function StartTimer( seconds ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.clearTimeout(runTimer);
        moveToNextSlide();
    }, seconds * 1000);
}
```

### 12) Read the source code from other image slideshow to find out better techniques.

Here's a place to start. http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/08/jquery-image-slider.html

### Final Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="abc-container">
                <div id="a" class="box"></div>
                <div id="b" class="box"></div>
                <div id="c" class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="asas"></div>
       <!-- !!!    Use script tag to import "main.js" -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var carouselTimer, runTimer, firstval = 0, 
    boxWidth = 400, abc_container = 1200,
    infoEl = document.getElementById('asas'), 
    container = document.getElementById('abc-container');

function moveToNextSlide() {
    firstval += 10;
    if( abc_container < firstval ){
        firstval = 0;
        return;
    }
    container.style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
    infoEl.innerHTML = "container.style.left.px = " + firstval;
    if (firstval % boxWidth) {
        carouselTimer = setTimeout(moveToNextSlide, 10);
    }else{
        window.clearTimeout(carouselTimer);
        StartTimer( 2 );
    }
}
function StartTimer( seconds ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.clearTimeout(runTimer);
        moveToNextSlide();
    }, seconds * 1000);
}
StartTimer( 2 );
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:140px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin: -70px 0 0 -200px;
    background: #383838;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#abc-container {
    position: absolute;
    width:1200px;
    height:140px;
}
#a {
    background: #FF0000;
}
#b {
    background: #FFFF00;
}
#c {
    background: #00FFFF;
}
.box{
    width:400px;
    height:140px;
    float: left; 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vSWmx/2

Comment: Hi Thanks for you help Larry, It's very very very great, I love it!! Thanks

Comment: do you have an idea to make it looping?

Comment: @user1697962 It's looping becuase of this condition. `if( abc_container < firstval ){ firstval = 0; }`

Comment: @user1697962 I updated the animation so it only cycles once. Another call to `moveToNextSlide()` will start the cycle again.

Comment: I would have add "do not use IDs for CSS"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything in [Larry's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15963/120114) and there is one other big point, which may be implied in the **Final Code**: indentation is crucial for readability.

There isn't an official "*correct*" indentation amount but general conventions call for two or four spaces when starting a block. For example, the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html) calls for 2 spaces:

> Each time a new block or block-like construct is opened, the indent increases by two spaces. When the block ends, the indent returns to the previous indent level. The indent level applies to both code and comments throughout the block.<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-block-indentation)</sup>

Meanwhile, Doug Crockford's [*Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language*](https://crockford.com/javascript/code.html) recommends 4 spaces.

> Every statement should begin aligned with the current indentation. The outermost level is at the left margin. The indentation increases by 4 spaces when the last token on the previous line is `{`*`left brace`*, `[`*`left bracket`*, `(`*`left paren`*. The matching closing token will be the first token on a line, restoring the previous indentation.<sup>[2](https://crockford.com/javascript/code.html#whitespace)</sup>

The [first version of your code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/15948/1) appears to have various levels of indentation:

> ```
> var runCarousel, runTimer;
>     firstval = 0;
>     secondval = 0;
>
>    function Carousel(){
>     firstval += 10;
>     document.getElementById('abc-container').style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
>     document.getElementById('asas').innerHTML = "-" + firstval;
>         if(firstval == 400)
>         {
>             StopRun();
>             StartTimer()
>             return;
>         }
>         //...
> ```

To format this consistently, use a consistent indentation:

```
var runCarousel, runTimer;
firstval = 0;
secondval = 0;

function Carousel(){
    firstval += 10;
    document.getElementById('abc-container').style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
    document.getElementById('asas').innerHTML = "-" + firstval;
    if(firstval == 400)
    {
        StopRun();
        StartTimer()
        return;
    }
```

And the same also applies to the CSS.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-block-indentation</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>https://crockford.com/javascript/code.html#whitespace</sub>